# Among 42 processes as outlined by the PMBOK, which process is important for SMEs?

Tags: pmbok

PMBOK has defined 42 management processes. Yet, not all the processes are relevant or some are less important according to the organization's size. I am doing a survey which objective in mind is to identify which process is important for Small Medium Enterprise in performing software project. I believe that there are too many processes in the PMBOK that SMEs need to adopt. In your opinion which processes are important for SMEs?

Comment: Your question is too vague. The short answer is to only adopt processes that make sense for your project, and adopt them to the right level. Without better context it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: SME is Subject Matter Expert. Did you perhaps mean SBE - Small Business Enterprise?

Comment: It refer to Small Medium Enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it is a mistake to try to identify what processes would be important for *any* type of project or business, no matter the attribute, through a survey like this.  You stand up and deploy those processes that you need.  And the need is dictated by what you are producing.

Work right to left instead of left to right.  What are you producing?  What do you need to produce in order to produce what you are producing?  Once you identify the outputs, then choose the processes you need to develop them, then identify the inputs you need.

Every project is unique.  One process would be terribly important on one project, then completely irrelevant another.

Comment: PMBOK by its nature provides little operational guidance in managing projects. This generality can lead to inappropriate activities if it is being applied to managing projects.  It might be confusing especially for the project manager with less experienced to choose which one is the best and suitable to be used bcoz too many tools and technique in PMBOK. Also for fresh PMP doesn't know what output must or should be produced. So how to assist them unless you give them a guideline this a basic process that you must have and some other process is optional depending on the context e.g. complexity?

Comment: The capability of a project manager--and all roles, really--is the combination of skill, knowledge, and practice.  Junior PMs need to grow these three things, which simply takes time, exposure, a few failures, and a lot of mentorship and coaching.  This simply takes time.  Trying to create a laundry list of "approved" PMBoK processes or activities will not grow any of those three things and, as I suggested, will likely just put you at grave risk for your projects.  These is no easy solution; you need to train, mentor, and coach them until their capabilities mature.